# VS Code Jest fails starting on Ubuntu 20.04 (ubuntu-make install)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, nvm, ubuntu-20.04

Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04 (official Beta Version)
- Visual Studio Code 1.44.2, installed via ubuntu-make (umake):
  `umake ide visual-studio-code`
- Node 12 via `nvm install 12 && nvm alias default 12 && nvm use default`
- VS Code Extension: jest

Error

- Restarting VS Code fails with:

```
Finished running all tests. Starting watch mode.
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
Starting Jest in Watch mode failed too many times and has been stopped.
 see troubleshooting: https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting
```

I want to use nvm and want to avoid workaround like adjusting bashrc or similar.

Did not work:

- Add to VS Code `settings.json` (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, "Open Settings Json"):

  - entry `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"`

Answer (score 1):

Just had an issue running commands over ssh where the node binary from nvm would not be added to the non-login shell's path so couldn't be used. Can't figure out how to add it there and keep it relative to the installed user to be honest.

Removing nvm and installing `apt install nodejs` through the default repositories is quick workaround if you need.

Comment: Thanks, I found this workaround, too, but I would like to get it to work with `nvm` instead.